# Python regex: Extract string between multiple dashes

Tags: python, regex

I have transcripts of speeches which have the following structure:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Person 1 [1]
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

           Text spoken by Person 1

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Person 2    [2]
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
           Text spoken by Person 2

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Person 3    [3]
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
           Text spoken by Person 3
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Person 2    [4]
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        
           Text spoken by Person 2
    
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Person 4    [5]
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
           Text spoken by Person 4
```

I use the following regex to extract the text spoken by Person 2:

```
regex_pattern= r"Person 2\s+\[\d+\]\s+-+\s+((?:.*?\n?)*(?=\s+-+|$))"
```

The regex works alright but in some instances, the written text includes two hyphens (--) which I want to account for.
For example:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Person 2    [12]
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

     Bla bla bla -- bla bla bla bla -- bla bla bla bla 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Person 6    [13]
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     Bla bla bla bla bla
```

The solution has to be fairly easy but somehow I didn't manage to get it right.
Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Maybe `(?ms)Person 2\s+\[\d+\]\s+^-+\s+(.*?)(?=\s+^-+|\Z)`? See https://regex101.com/r/kKXSse/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
(?ms)Person 2\s+\[\d+\]\s+^-+\s+(.*?)(?=\s+^-+|\Z)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kKXSse/1).

*Details*:

- `(?ms)` - `m` makes `^` match any line start position and `$` match any end of line position, and `s` makes the `.` match any char including line break chars
- `Person 2` - a literal text
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `\[\d+\]` - `[` + one or more digits + `]`
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `^` - start of a line
- `-+` - one or more `-`s
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `(.*?)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars as few as possible
- `(?=\s+^-+|\Z)` - up to one or more whitespaces, followed with a line start position and then one or more `-`s, or end of the whole text.

Comment: Just a quick follow-up: How do I have to adjust the regex to control for cases where "Person 2" might not be the first phrase in the line and for cases where other characters appear between "Person 2" and the brackets. E.g., "xyz Person 2, bla 123 [4]

Comment: @xxgaryxx This is not clear, but perhaps you can rely in the `[^\[]*` construct that matches any zero or more chars other than `[` as many as possible. Use `(?ms)Person 2\b[^\[]*\[\d+\]\s+^-+\s+(.*?)(?=\s+^-+|\Z)` and see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kKXSse/2).

Comment: Thanks! Seem to work, except that it will also match the first text that is transcripted in my document. See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/v3BGQa/1) where the text from the Operator is also matched even though I only want to match the text spoken by the CEO.

Comment: @xxgaryxx Then you may restrict the match before the hyphen only line appears: `(?ms)CEO\b(?:(?!\n-+$).)*?\[\d+\]\s+^-+\s+(.*?)(?=\s+^-+|\Z)`

Comment: Thank you. After running some test it appears that I only matching on "CEO" is prone to errors. As a solution I want to match on the the CEO Name as well as on the words CEO|Chief Executive Officer.
Unfortunately, combining the CEO name with the position CEO|Chief Executive Officer does not work yet. See: https://regex101.com/r/v3BGQa/2

Comment: @xxgaryxx I am not sure what the expected results are.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear in my previous comment. The output is expected to be the same, i.e., I want to extract all parts of a CEOs speech. However, instead of simply matching on the expression „CEO“ or „Chief executive officer“ I also want to include the CEOs Name in the regex. 
The name are given at the very top of each document unter „corporate participants“. I already managed to extract the CEOs name and save it in a variable. In the regex Demo I tried this based on the CEO’s name „Michael T. Strianese„ but it won’t work unfortunately.

Comment: @xxgaryxx I still don't know what the expected output is. See https://regex101.com/r/v3BGQa/3, maybe it will give you some clues.

Comment: Thanks. I managed to get closer to what I would like to achieve.
See my updated approach: https://regex101.com/r/v3BGQa/4
This will only match if the expression Michael T\. Strianese,  L3 Technologies, Inc\. - Chairman and CEO is observed between the hyphens instead of just looking for the string "CEO".
Now I want to adjust this so it will match regardless the text between the CEO name Michael T\. Strianese and the string "CEO". I tried the following, with no success unfortunately:
(?ms)Michael T\. Strianese.?CEO\s*\[\d+\]\s+^-+\s+(.*?)(?=\s+^-+|\Z)

Comment: @xxgaryxx Maybe https://regex101.com/r/v3BGQa/5 will do.